# Form to open URL slash the viarable (e.g localhost/"user entry")

Tags: forms, url

I need form with one text box and submit button, and that's should be used for taking number from the user and open my site url + the number.

For example:
User will type in the text field : 44
Then he press the button.
The page should take the number and open a link like this :
http://localhost/44

Comment: People on stackoverflow won't write code for you if you haven't tried anything. Create your form elements using html and then, using javascript, get the input of the user and call window.location.href = "/" + user_input;

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='http://example.com'>
    <input type="text" name="number">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This will give me : localhost/?number=44 , i dont want to put ?number on the URL, just i want localhost/44

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jquery + form like below may help you

```
<form method="get">
<input type="text" name="num" id="num" />
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Go">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('.submit').live('click',function(){

var url = "http://www.example.com";
var input = $('#num').val();
alert(input);
window.location.href=url+'/'+input;

});
</script>
```